# Keeping a VOIP socket alive in background - iOS 9

Tags: ios, ios9, pushkit

I know that I can keep a socket alive in the background for VOIP applications with kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP. However this is deprecated on iOS 9 and they recommend to use the PushKit Framework for VOIP purposes.

My problem is that my App is suppose to work without internet connectivity so I have no way of using remote notifications. The App connects to a SIP device for VOIP calling purposes.

Any suggestions would be helpful for a future proof solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

By the way, when building with the iOS 10+ SDK, this feature has been removed entirely. See [QA1938](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/qa/qa1938/_index.html). Apple does mention that some applications like yours don't have access to the Internet, but then says the only way to do it is for you to open certain ports to the APNS servers, which still requires some Internet, so it doesn't really answer your question.

> Some VoIP apps are specifically designed to work in special networks,
>   ones that don’t provide access to the wider Internet. To use PushKit
>   in such an environment you must configure the network to allow iOS
>   devices to access the Apple Push Notification Service. See TCP and UDP
>   ports used by Apple software products for information on how to do
>   this.